# Requirejs Optimizer r.js not working with node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs, r.js

I am trying to build my project with r.js requirejs plugin but I am not able to get generated output file. compiling successfully.

build.js

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    paths : {
        plugins : "lib",
        underscore : "lib/underscore-min",
        backbone : "lib/backbone-min",
        text : "lib/text",

    },
    mainConfigFile:"app",
    name: "app",
    out: "akorp-built.js"
})
```

Directory structure

```
project
 |
 |--js
 |   |--lib
 |   |--modules
 |   |--app.js
 |   |--require-jquery.js
 |   |--build.js
 |
 |--css
r.js
```

Command

```
node r.js -o project/js/build.js
```

compiling but not generating output file.

I tried this, I wonder compiled without 'build.js' file in directory

```
 node r.js -o build.js
```

Is anything wrong on my side?

Comment: Since you are using node you should consider using [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to build your projects. There is a [requirejs plugin for grunt available now](https://github.com/asciidisco/grunt-requirejs).

Answer (score 1):

Move r.js to the same directory as build.js. Then make sure current directory in the command line is set to that directory. If it's on windows, just call:

```
cd /d %~dp0
node r.js -o build.js
PAUSE
```